# How to find out duplicate in two lists of coordinates?

Tags: python, coordinates

I have two lists of coordinates, which is the start point and end point of routes. I need to find out which route connect to which route. i.e. start_point of a route == end_point of another route.
So I need to figure out the duplicated coordinates in start_point and end_point.

For example,

```
start_point = [[1,2],[2,4],[3,5]]
end_point = [[3,3],[3,4],[3,5]]
```

I expect to get [3,5] as a return.
Is there any build in function of python or package can accomplish this goal? or do I need to write a recursive loop for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate in parallel, and a list comprehension:

```
start_point = [[1,2],[2,4],[3,5]]
end_point = [[3,3],[3,4],[3,5]]

out = [s for s,e in zip(start_point, end_point) if s==e]
```

output:

```
[[3, 5]]
```

Comment: thank you. However, the duplicated coordinates are mostly not appear in parallel. I just simplify my question there. I got 3000 start_point and end_point. I need to find out if coordinates in listA match any of the coordinates in listB and print them out

Comment: OK, I initially added this as remark in my answer then deleted not to clutter the post, you can use set operations: `set(map(tuple, start_point)) & set(map(tuple, end_point))` -> `{(3, 5)}`. I see it's been posted in another answer now

Comment: Thank you! that solves my problem. but I just encounter another problem now. Could you help me to take a look? I just describe the problem right down there.

Comment: I don't see the update of your problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to get the intersection of two lists.
Here is an approach I would prefer

```
res= set(map(tuple, start_point )) & set(map(tuple, end_point ))
res_list = list(map(list, res))
```

To get intersection, I am converting the list into set and performing AND operation on it. Then converting it back to list.

For more details you can check [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-intersection-of-two-nested-list/)

Comment: thank you so much! that solves my problem. May I ask another question? Each coordinates in the lists got an unique index. How can I figure out the index of the intersection point in two list respectively? e.g. For[3,5], the index of [3,5] is 10 in Start_point, while the index in end_point is 5. I expect to get something like (10,5) in a new list for all the intersection point.

Comment: @Ivan, You can do reverse search of your intersection output on list to get output. Once you find it append it on list , do the same for both and you will have your answer.

Comment: I know this can be done this way, but do I have any method to do it in a more "programming" way? As there are 2000+ intersection points. It is very time-consuming to do it this way.

Comment: I am not sure but I think Numpy will help you on this

Answer (score 0):

```
# Method 1 : Using for loop
for item in end_point:
  if item in start_point:
    print(item)

# Method 2 : Using List Compression
print([sublist for sublist in end_point if sublist in start_point])
```

Output:

```
[3, 5]
[[3, 5]]
```